# Posting with Alamofire

Tags: ios, swift, alamofire, swifty-json

I'm trying to Post something to my server with Alamofire but I can't get it to work. In Postman it looks like this:

[image]

This is my code:

```
func uploadDish(dish:Dish, completionHandler: ((AnyObject?, ErrorType?) -> Void)){

        let urlString = "http://backend-url/secret/v1/something"

        // build parameters
        let parameters = [
            "name": "test",
            "address": "test",
            "priceRange": "1",
            "lat": 9999,
            "lng": 9999
        ]

        // build request
        Alamofire.request(.POST, urlString, parameters: parameters, encoding: .URL).responseJSON { response in

            switch response.result {

            case .Success(let value):
                let json = JSON(value)
                print(json)
            case .Failure(let error):
                let json = JSON(error)
                print(json)
            }
        }
    }
```

The error I get is:

Failure NSError domain: "NSCocoaErrorDomain" - code: 3840   0x00007f96717be8e0

Screenshot of the error:

[image]

Comment: What's the error description saying?

Comment: Updated the original post with another screenshot

Comment: The error message you are getting is not JSON convertible. The issue is here: `let json = JSON(error)`. Just delete it and do `print(error.localizedDescription)`

Comment: This is what gets printed: "The data couldn’t be read because it isn’t in the correct format."

Comment: It is a server side error. Are you sure the parameter encoding should be `.URL` instead of `.JSON`?

Comment: I am not sure. The first screenshot of the Postman request works though. When I change .URL to .JSON I get this error: "Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=3840 "Invalid value around character 0." UserInfo={NSDebugDescription=Invalid value around character 0.}"

Comment: I found out my server wants a 'multipart form data POST'. How to do this with the above request in code?

Comment: `Alamofire.upload(.POST, ...)`

Comment: Just chaging .request to .upload leads to compile errors

Comment: remove `, encoding: .URL` and check if still error?

Answer (score 0):

```
    let parameterDic:[String:AnyObject] = [
        "name": "test",
        "address": "test",
        "priceRange": "1",
        "lat": 9999,
        "lng": 9999
    ]
```

Comment: Please add an explanation to you answer.

Answer (score 0):

Add type:

```
let parameters = [String : String] = [
    "name": "test",
    "address": "test",
    "priceRange": "1",
    "lat": "9999",
    "lng": "9999"
]
```